# How to set timeout on error SSH Exec node.js

Tags: node.js

in my node js script, I use remote connection to run a script on RPI ssh via ssh-exec,
Sometimes the script fails and a reboot of the system is required, in order to let the system come back I need to wait 2 minutes,

I have tried the next thing:

runScript()
Await sleep(60000)

```
function runScript() {
        let exec = require('ssh-exec');
        let v_host = '';
        let ssh = exec('sudo RunScript', {
            user: 'user',
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            password: 'password'
        });
        ssh.pipe(process.stdout, function (data) {
            console.log("8started");
            console.log(data);
        });
        ssh.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("\n\nREBOOT\n\n");
            reboot();
            console.log("time out on");
            setTimeout(runScript, 120000);
        });
    }

async function reboot() {
    let exec = require('ssh-exec');
    let ssh = exec('sudo reboot', {
        user: 'user',
        host: ip,
        password: 'password'
    });
    ssh.pipe(process.stdout, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    ssh.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But the script just keeps running and the thread is not waiting for 2 minutes,

I will be glad to have some help as I tried many

Comment: you don't need setTimeout, call runScript function in reboot function

Comment: @virender nehra , without any timeout or sleep? The run script itself is not a promise so I have to se sleep(60000) everytime I use it to wait it complete during 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Call runScript in reboot

```
function runScript() {
        let exec = require('ssh-exec');
        let v_host = '';
        let ssh = exec('sudo RunScript', {
            user: 'user',
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            password: 'password'
        });
        ssh.pipe(process.stdout, function (data) {
            console.log("8started");
            console.log(data);
        });
        ssh.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("\n\nREBOOT\n\n");
            reboot();
        });
    }

async function reboot() {
    let exec = require('ssh-exec');
    let ssh = exec('sudo reboot', {
        user: 'user',
        host: ip,
        password: 'password'
    });
    ssh.pipe(process.stdout, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        runScript()
    });
    ssh.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: When i do ,sudo reboot doesn't the ssh lose connection? Also Both of those functions run and doesn't make the main script to stop, so it means after i call runScript(); sleep(60); and there is an error that requires reboot the main script will keep doing stuff after 60 seconds

Comment: Yes, its working if using sudo reboot, then server loses connection and reboots via 2 minutes

Comment: so when your system reboot your nodeJs queue also cleared and you setTimeout does't work, in that case do one thing just store a flag in file or db and when you start your node server after rebooting check the file/db if and run script.

Comment: I used a flag to reboot and delay the thread and it works! Thank you